# SSL + .jks + Python

Tags: python, ssl, apache-kafka, jks

I have cert in .jks format. I use python and I'd like to write consumer, which is using this cert. I don't know how to do this by pyjks. This cert was using in Java earlier. Can you help and explain how to do it?

```
ks = jks.KeyStore.load(path,pass)
consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic, boostrap_servers=[client], security_protocol='SSL', #ssl_cafile= ks.certs, #ssl_certfile=ks.cert , #ssl_keyfile=ks.private_keys}
```

How cen i get ssl_cafile, ssl_certfile and ssl_keyfile?

Comment: You need to convert the JKS to PEM files. There are resources on the web that can help with this

Comment: i found that i can do it by keytool but im not sure that it is the simplest way?

Comment: Java `keytool` command mostly works with JKS, I believe. `openssl` commands are generally used instead

Comment: You are right but i don't know how to get cafile and keyfile?